# Disable a sibling button if reactive form field is not valid Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a component with a reactive form in it like so...

**form component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="do-form">
    <div formGroupName="dot">
        <div class="do-form__container">
            <div class="do-form__group">
                <label for="day">Day</label>
                <input id="day" type="number" placeholder="XX" class="do-form__group__control" formControlName="day" />
            </div>
            <div class="do-form__group">
                <label for="month">Month</label>
                <input id="month" type="number" placeholder="XX" class="do-form__group__control" formControlName="month" />
            </div>
            <div class="do-form__group">
                <label for="year">Year</label>
                <input id="year" type="number" placeholder="XXXX" class="do-form__group__control" formControlName="year" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="do-form__errors" *ngIf="isValid()">
            <p>Please enter a valid date</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in my **form.component.ts**

```
form = this.fb.group({
dot: this.fb.group({
  day: ['',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(1),
      Validators.max(31)
    ]],
  month: ['',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(1),
      Validators.max(12)
    ]],
  year: ['2018',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(1918),
      Validators.max(2018)
    ]]
})
});

isValid() {
return (
  !this.form.valid &&
  this.form.get('dot.day').touched &&
  this.form.get('dot.month').touched &&
  this.form.get('dot.year').touched
);
}
```

Now I have a separate page (app.component.html) like so

```
<app-form #formTool></app-form>
        <button class="full-width-btn" (click)="next(); form.sendResult();">SEND</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {  formComponent } from '../form-component/form-component.ts'

export ...

@ViewChild(formComponent) form;
```

Now basically I want to disable the send button until the form in the app form component is valid.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this. I thought about storing a `valid` event on a shared server but I'm not sure how I can store a `valid` event in a service. I saw that with non-reactive forms you can just have a button that uses the same `ngModel` but once again not sure if that would work in this case.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have tried `[disabled]="form.invalid"` and `[disabled]="!isValid()"` but I am still able to click the button

I have also tried using `[disabled]=!form.isValid()` and `[disabled]=!form.form.isValid()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In form component you could define an event @Output formValid = new EventEmitter().

Then you can listen to changes in input fields (on keypress or so) and on any change check the validity and if the form is valid, emit an event: formValid.emit().

In the app component define formIsValid = false, and on the app-form element you can listen to the formValid event:
    < app-form (formValid)="formIsValid = true">
(or some function in app.component.ts instead of the inline code).

And finally on button
    < button [disabled]="!formIsValid">

Answer (score 3):

You are really close. Here is the only thing you need to add:

```html
<app-form #formTool></app-form>
<button class="full-width-btn" [disabled]="!isValid()" (click)="next(); form.sendResult();">SEND</button>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! but could you please tell me how this button knows whether or not it is valid?? like how are they communicating? I know I have a viewChild set up to call the function of sendResult is that how they are 'talking'?

Comment: You have already written the `isValid()` function that can just be re-used within the HTML. If you didn't have that function written, then you could have used `[disabled]="form.invalid"` instead or something else like that. The reference to the `form` object and its states are what allows for the reactive form to set the `[disabled]` property on the button.

Comment: Hey I tried both ways you said and Im still able to click the send button without the forms being valid is there something im missing?

Comment: You are going to have to post more of your code in order for me to help because it should be working based on the code you have provided.

Comment: I will update my question, when I have `isValid()` in there Im getting a `!co.isValid() is not a function error`

Comment: Please check updated answer and let me know if you need any more information